# Why can’t Internet Explorer access my Django Development Server that’s accessible externally (i.e. not on localhost?)

Tags: python, django, localhost

I've been tasked by my programming teacher to learn Django. However, I need to code on a command line linux box and therefore cannot access the web page from said linux box.

To test, I need to host it on the local IP of the computer rather than localhost. I’m currently running the Django development server using this command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Firefox and Chrome can access the development server at the Linux box’s IP address, but Internet Explorer can’t.

Comment: why can't you have a web page and command line on the same linux host?

Comment: @tMC I'm thinking he means a server edition linux box with no GUI, like ubuntu server (which is what i use). He's probably programming though SSH access. As mentioned below, specifying a port will allow you to see it on networked machines. Or, just set up a full blown server- try [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) - [easy guide to gunicorn setup](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2010/aug/16/lessons-learned-dash-easy-django-deployment/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately (I am said teacher), I can't provide a linux host - only a linux server and a windows host to do development on.

He's actually running the web server correctly, with the command provided by Paul. But for some reason, it's only visible in Firefox/Chrome, IE just provides a generic "Webpage cannot be displayed"

But this problem can be solved by using the entire address: http:// isn't optional like it is in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Ah, this might be better as a comment on the question. I’ve edited the question to include this information — if I understand you right, the Django development server *is* serving on the Linux box’s external IP address, but not to Internet Explorer?

Comment: You're right. Should have been a comment. But I edited a minute later to add a solution. Just wasn't expecting you to be so fast!

Comment: heh! I was quite quick off the mark there. Glad the issue got clarified and solved.

Comment: This did not fix the problem for me. I'm running my Django App in development mode on 0.0.0.0:8000 and I can load the site in FF and Chrome, but not IE. Adding http:// did not fix the problem.

Comment: Ultimately I had to change my hosts file to point a made up domain to my server's ip address, then make sure to add the port to the fake domain in my web browser. It worked for me, if it isn't working for you try flushing your dns cache or restarting your computer.

Answer (score 5):

When you run the development server, you can make it available on the local network by specifying the IP address `0.0.0.0` for it, like this:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

If your Linux box’s local IP address is e.g. 192.168.1.37, you’d access the development server at:

```
http://192.168.1.37:8000
```

Comment: Just to confirm (I'm not a network guru :), when you say the server is "available externally", you mean to any machine on the *local network*. That is, using all zeros for the IP will get the address from your router, which is 192.168, and *not* the dynamic address my ISP assigns to my router - correct?

Comment: @John C: ah — I suspect you’re correct, but I’m even *less* of a network guru, so I’m not entirely sure. I’ll amend my answer accordingly though.

Answer (score 1):

Setup nginx to listen on a public port and proxy all of the requests to the django runserver.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the IP clearly in the command line like this in order to let other clients to access. You also have to enable the port 8000 in the firewall:

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.37:8000
```

Comment: 0.0.0.0:8000 does the same thing